# Dask lowest than vanilla python? What is what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-delayed

I'm testing dask and i can't understand how dask is slower that plain python. I was developed in jupyer two examples to get the time for each, and i think that i am doing something wrong

The first with dask: 28.5 seconds and after in plain python 140 ms

```
    import dask
    import dask.array as da
    %%time
    def inc(x):
        return x + 1

    def double(x):
        return x + 2

    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    N = 100000

    data = [0 for x in range(N)]
    x = da.from_array(data, chunks=(1000))

    output = []
    for x in data:
        a = dask.delayed(inc)(x)
        b = dask.delayed(double)(x)
        c = dask.delayed(add)(a, b)
        output.append(c)

    total = dask.delayed(sum)(output)
    total.compute()
```

```
**28.8 seconds**
```

Now with plain python

```
    %%time
    def inc(x):
        return x + 1

    def double(x):
        return x + 2

    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    N = 100000

    data = [0 for x in range(N)]

    output = []
    for x in data:
        a = inc(x)
        b = double(x)
        c = add(a, b)
        output.append(c)

    total = sum(output)
```

```
**140 milliseconds**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code run on my machine: 38s.
This code:

```
x = da.from_array(data, chunks=(1000))
%time ((x + 1) + (2*x)).compute()
```

runs in 24ms.

```
x = np.array(data)
%time ((x + 1) + (2*x))
```

runs in 350us.

Points:

- is your data fits in memory easily (numpy or pandas), you probably don't get anything from dask, since those libraries are already fast
- Dask has collection APIs like array, so use them
- don't `for`-iterate over arrays!
- if an individual function runs in a time <<1ms, dask is only adding overhead; this is certainly your case. You'll notice in the tutorial that the functions include `sleep` to simulate CPU work, so that you actually get some parallelism
- don't call `.compute()` many many times, try to form what you want to do into a single call to compute, which takes an arbitrary number of arguments.